# how to make UIImageView clickable (touchable) with an iTunes link or a Google search

Tags: ios, url, uiimageview, touch, itunes

I have a few static household ads in an UIImageView that just display some text for now. I'd like to make them clickable, so when the user touches the UIImageView it opens an iTunes link or Safari with a predefined Google search.

What's the best approach here ?

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason that you can't use a UIButton?

You can set the image of a UIButton and then make that touchable via IB or in code.

Comment: worked like a charm. thank you! ... just for future reference:  http://itunes.apple.com/linkmaker?  is a very useful link.